# Node.js - Argument in an anonymous function without passing it a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I come from a C/C++ background and I'm having real trouble trying to wrap my head around the syntax of node.js. Anyway, I found some code online to explain the difference between blocking and non-blocking code, and it's had me stumped for hours. I've tried searching and reading books but just can't find an answer to this. The example code retrieves a user ID from a database.

**Blocking Version:**

```
function getUser(id) {
   var user = db.query(id);
   return user;
}

console.log('Name: ' + getUser(432).name);
```

**Non-Blocking Version (Node.js):**

```
function getUser(id, callback) {
   db.query(id, callback);
}

getUser(432, function (user) {
   console.log(user.name);
});
```

I'm fine with the Blocking version because in that instance, the user ID is assigned to the variable `user`. What I just can't seem to understand is the `user` argument in the anonymous function. It seems that `user` just appears out of nowhere and then has instructions acted upon it, without any relationship to an existing variable.

How does the program know what `user` is? How does it even make any connection with the user's ID? I honestly can't tell if it's my lack of knowledge of JavaScript/Node, or whether the person who wrote this code didn't bother to complete it. All I know is, this makes no sense in C/C++.

Comment: Maybe you have read a wrong tutorial (could you link it please?). Blocking vs. non-blocking has nothing to do with syntax per se. You will have to consult the docs of `db.query` to check whether it's asynchronous (which you cannot change), and then use the appropriate syntax for that.

Comment: Blocking and non-blocking is the topic I'm interested in. I'm just trying to understand the examples this person posted. The link is [link](http://hueniverse.com/2011/06/29/the-style-of-non-blocking/)

Comment: Yeah, OK, that article is not that bad. Just make sure to understand that the `db.query` function in the blocking examples is a completely different function than the `db.query` in the non-blocking ones (which takes a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))). If you're coming from C, you might want to take a look at the example in that Wikipedia article.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I'll have a read through now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you've asked the program to fetch you a user, and supplied with a function that accepts an argument (or more, depending on the library). After the operation is complete, `getUser` will invoke the callback you passed with the result of the operation.

Here's a dummy getUser implementation for you:

```
function getUser(id, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var result = {id: id, name: "Madara"};
        callback(result);
    }, 1000); // Wait a second before doing it. Asynchronous!
}

getUser(42, function(user) { console.log(user); });
```

That function will wait one second, and then **invoke** the callback you pass with one argument, in this case, an object with the ID you passed, and "Madara" as the name.

Notice that there's nothing blocking with `getUser`, so `getUser` returns *immediately*, and without waiting for the callback to be called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

In your dummy code you have added `callback(result);` This is what I feel is missing from the Non-Blocking example I posted. That's what I'm confused about. I can't understand how the result is being passed to the anonymous function, without having a statement like this.

Comment: @winger There is a statement like that, but it is in the `db.query` function, which is presumably part of a library.

Comment: @AaronDufour Thank you! I was starting to think this language was using background magic

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help you if I translate your example into C.
I haven't used C in a long time but I think it would look like this.

```
void getUser(int id, void (*callback)(User)) {
   db.query(id, callback);
}

void printUserName(User user) {
  printf(user.name);
}

getUser(432, &printUserName);
```